# Can I use AWS API Gateway in front of Kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I want to create an HTTP endpoint that will collect data and save them in Kinesis Streams. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Look at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html

If you want more flexibility you probably want to marshall the calls through Lambda, but it's not necessary.